# Unlocking Encrypted Drive after too many unsuccessful attempts

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, encryption, unlock

I have a FileVault encrypted disk partition on the internal SSD of my Monterey M1 MacBook Pro.

I entered the wrong password too many times and now when trying to mount an encrypted drive in Disk Utility I'm getting the following message:

> This disk cannot be unlocked

Trying using terminal I get:

```
diskutil apfs unlockvolume disk3s7 -user disk
```

But I get the following error:

> Too many recent unlock attempts; unlocking disabled

I was previously being timed out after too many wrong password attempts. Any idea how I can unlock and mount this disk?

Comment: What OS, what Mac, is the disk FileVault encrypted, is it internal or external?

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the prompt, question updated.

Comment: Ah, OK. That's a toughie...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Mac with Secure Enclave or a T2 chip, once you have exceeded the 10 attempts you will need a trip to the Apple Store with proof of ownership.

Before that, if you think you might have nearly remembered it & want another go, you can get 10 more attempts from Recovery.

If these also fail, then there are ten more attempts for FileVault recovery mode. If all 30 attempts are wrong, the Secure Enclave closes. Mac models with a T2 security chip have the option of using iCloud recovery, FileVault recovery and similar measures.

Source: [Wrong password and unlock code: You have so many attempts on Mac and iPhone!](https://www.sir-apfelot.de/en/wrong-password-and-unlock-code-you-have-so-many-attempts-on-mac-and-iphone-43284/)